# how to see how many power-down / power-up cycles a drive has gone through?

Tags: hard-disk

I recently used a utility on Linux that reported the number of shutdowns / restarts that a hard disk had gone through (I believe the terminology used was "power cycles") but I can't seem to recall which one.

Is there a way to obtain to information on a given disk's age and number of shutdowns / restarts it has gone through ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drives give this information *via* [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.). You can retrieve it using `smartctl` (in [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/)):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

This will output quite a lot of information, including:

```
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       36065
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       175
```

which shows that this particular drive has been powered on (in total) for 36,065 hours, and powered on 175 times.